# Call a Matlab function from c++

Tags: c++, matlab, shell

I have a small code snippet that calls a matlab function (saved in its own .m file). The user can choose the matlab function to call and it may or may not be in MATLAB's default folder (~/Documents/MATLAB).

In the event that it's not in the default search path, I would like to add the function's containing folder to MATLAB's search path. When I try to do this using the Terminal (I am on a MAC), with this command:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/matlab -r "addpath(genpath('/Folder/Address/Here'))"
```

MATLAB launches, and I can see that the new address was successfully added to the search path.

However, when I try to run this command through the C++ program using this:

```
std::string  matlabFunctionPath = "/Folder/Address/Here"
std::string  addPathCommand = "/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/matlab -r \"addpath(genpath('"+ matlabFunctionPath + "')\"";
::popen(shellCommand.c_str(), "r"));
```

MATLAB does launch but the new address does not get added to the search path. What am I doing wrong here?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the second closing `)`

```
std::string  addPathCommand = "/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/matlab -r \"addpath(genpath('"+ matlabFunctionPath + "'))\"";
```